# Using code blocks in markdown after "*"

Tags: markdown

I'm not getting the correctly format when using code block after a "*" mark, like this:

```
* Here are the places
  * blablabla
  * unit X:

for(I=0;I<100;I++)
{
  ....
}
```

it looks like:

- Here are the places

  - blablabla
  - unit X:

  for(I=0;I<100;I++)
  {
    ....
  }

Comment: You need to indent the code block more, much more, for lists. Even more for nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

Separate your list and your code block with an empty HTML comment:

```
* Here are the places
* blablabla
    * unit X:

<!-- -->

    for(I=0;I<100;I++) { .... }
```

Rendered:

- Here are the places
- blablabla

  - unit X:

```
for(I=0;I<100;I++) { .... }
```

As noted below, some renderers [will accept a language hint in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Also, nested lists should use four spaces at each level of indentation.

Comment: @Emissary, that's fine for Markdown on Stack Overflow (and likely some other places too) but it's not part of the [original definition of Markdown code blocks](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode). It shouldn't hurt anything though, since it's in a comment, and it's a useful addition. I'll update my answer.